# Ignore characters while reading file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I am reading a file, and I wish to ignore certain characters.

My file will be like this:

```
 5
 f1: A, B, 2
 f2: C, B, 5
 f3: C, D, 8
 2
 A, C
 B, D
```

I will be using a scanner.
Now, reading the first integer no problem, input.nextInt()

I get to the second line and here comes the problem. I want to ignore ":" and ","
I thought about using a BufferedReader and go character by character, but I wish to learn if its possible to do this using scanner.

I have been searching and there is:

```
   input.useDelimiter([\\:\\])
```

but it does not work. It throws an exception.

I also researched:

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W"); 
   // means any non-word characters, see details in the Pattern class
```

But I really don't know how it works.

So should I keep trying with scanner or go back to BufferedReader?

**How to solve it with scanner?**

Comment: Do you *have to* use Scanner? It's kind of annoying to use. Why not read the file line by line and parse it using your own code?

Comment: The code you posted for `useDelimiter` is not legal Java; can you please post the actual code? (Include all the code you use to set up the Scanner and how you use it.) What exception did you get?

Comment: @GregHewgill No i dont have to use Scanner. I guess i'll go back to using BufferedReader and read char by char. Sounds good?

Comment: No, I would recommend reading a whole *line* of text from the file using `readLine()`, and then splitting up the string using regular Java string manipulation.